# Extract a record by name in pyshp?

Tags: python, pyshp

I would like to extract a named subset of the text records from a shapefile using Python/pyshp. Is there a clean/efficient way to do this?

Ideally I'd like to use dictionary-like access such as:

```
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader("MyFile.shp")
data = sf.record['desired_record_name']
```

But of course this doesn't work. So far my solution is the brute force approach of looping over all entries:

```
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader("MyFile.shp")
for r in sf.iterRecords():
    if r[0]=='desired_record_name':
        data = r
        break
```

But this leaves a lot to be desired, especially for large/many files.

Note: Although I like the simplicity of pyshp, I am not tied to it, so other free & open-source solutions using python are also of interest.

Comment: If you are not hung up on dictionary access, just use OGR and write a SELECT statement for the records you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create a dictionary of attributes:

```
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader('MyFile.shp')
# name of fields
fields = sf.fields[1:] 
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields] 
# construction of a dctionary field_name:value  
for r in sf.shapeRecords():  
     atr = dict(zip(field_names, r.record))
```

As a result:

```
{'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2', ...,  'fieldn': 'valuen'}
```

and

```
if atr['field1'] == value:
       print atr
       action
```

With large/many files, you can use a generator:

```
def records(filename):  
    # generator 
    reader = shapefile.Reader(filename)  
    fields = reader.fields[1:]  
    field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]  
    for sr in reader.shapeRecords():   
        yield dict(zip(field_names, sr.record)) 
rec = records('MyFile.shp')
rec.next()
{'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2', ...,  'fieldn': 'valuen'}
# or
for rec in records('MyFile.shp')
     if rec['field1'] == value:
         data = rec
```

Sean Gillies has proposed the [The geo_interface protocol](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756), an interface that describes a spatial object using a GeoJSON like structure (dictionaries). Many modules implement this protocol (see [Python Geo_interface applications](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications)), including pyshp, since version 1.1.7:

With one of my examples:

```
for r in sf.shapeRecords():  
   atr = dict(zip(field_names, r.record))  
   geom = r.shape.__geo_interface__ 
   print dict(geometry=geom,properties=atr)  
   {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (161821.09375, 79076.0703125)}, 'properties': {'DIP_DIR': 120, 'STRATI_TYP': 1, 'DIP': 30}}
```

You can also use [Fiona](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications) or [osgeo.ogr](https://github.com/mlaloux/Python-geo_interface-applications/blob/master/ogr_geointerface.py) in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might use OGR's Python bindings to do this:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ds = ogr.Open(r"path_to\shapefile.shp")
lyr = ds.GetLayer()

# Apply a SQL WHERE Clause
lyr.SetAttributeFilter("FIELD = 'Value'")

# Loop over features
for feature in lyr:
    # do stuff with features selected by attribute filter
```

[`SetAttributeFilter`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#acb2c6cc5fa3577df5be538284c1b0dde) lets you apply a SQL WHERE clause, which filters the rows returned or affected by layer methods.

Answer (score 1):

Good news... The PyShp library has been updated to include this exact feature.

The newest version (2.0) is not available through PyPI or pip yet, but I would expect that to change soon.

Source: https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#major-changes

> Reading shapefiles is now more convenient:
>
> - More convenient accessing of Record values as attributes. [@philippkraft]